# Is "The crowd are loving this.", from a UK newspaper, acceptable?

Tags: grammar

Is "The crowd are loving this." acceptable grammar? I think it should be "The crowd is loving this."

Does it matter if it's a UK newspaper?

Comment: Grammar are strange in the UK.

Comment: It's not acceptable grammar to put a period in the quote. ;-)

Comment: I've never been to the UK, but from listening to BBC, et al, I get the impression that certain mass nouns such as "team" tend to be treated as if they meant "team members", eg, in contexts such as the quoted one.  I'm guessing that "crowd", "team", "squad", "crew", etc, are treated this way.

Comment: @AndyT  Oh. Ok. I think it should be "The crowd is loving this."